# How does Mac OS X VPS work?

Tags: virtualization, mac-osx, vps

How do folks like Xcloud for example provide Mac OS X VPS service? Do they run VMWare with Mac OS X guest instances, or is there a native(if that even makes sense) hypervisor that runs on something like Apple hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Apples terms of sale prohibit the virtualization of OS X on any other platform than OS X, they probably use Apple hardware - Apple discarded their XServe server series 2 years ago, so I guess, they are using Mac Pro's.

Comment: So they run VMWare on Mac Pro with OSX being guest system? WOuldn't the performance be pretty bad on such setup?

Comment: I'm only guessing, but due to the lack of a bare metal hypervisor for mac, I think they'll use either VMWare or Parallels.

Comment: @Henrik ESXi can run Mac VMs, though the licensing restriction of running on Apple hardware still applies: http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2005793

Comment: @Shane I already knew about this - even a lot more virtualisazion solution are able to do so (like Xen, Virtualbox) with more are less workarounds (for more information see http://www.tonymacx86.com/). Actually I'm virtualizing 10.6 with Virtualbox on Linux host system, because 10.6 is the last OS X where the TOS could be interpreted in this way, that virtualization is allowed on non-Apple Hardware. For 10.7 and later its impossible to do this legally :)